# Dynamic Table with rowspan

Tags: php

I have a table generated with a loop with column headers mon trough to fri and time array with 30min intervals for 24hr I have just shorten the example code:

```
$times = array(00:00, 00:30, 01:00, 01:30);
$skip = array();
$row = 1;
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Time</td><td>Mon</td><td>tue</td>
 <tr>
 foreach($times AS $val){
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
  SELECT `show`,`time_start`,`time_stop`,`show_day` 
  FROM `db_shows` WHERE `time_start`='$val'
  ");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($myrow[show],$myrow[time_start],$myrow[time_stop],$myrow[show_day]);
  $stmt->fetch();
  // GET THE ROWSPAN
  $a = new DateTime($myrow[time_start]);
  $b = new DateTime($myrow[time_stop]);
  $interval = $a->diff($b);
  $res = $interval->format('%h');
  $res *= 2;
  $res += 1;
  // ARRY FOR ROWS TO SKIP TD
  code in second part
  // APPLAY DISPLAY NONE IF NEEDED
  code in second part
  // BUILD COLUMNS
  switch($myrow[show_day]){
   case "":$tds = "<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>"; break;
   case "mon":$tds = "<td rowspan="$res" style="$mon">$myrow[show]</td><td>&nbsp;</td>"; break;
   case "tue":$tds = "<td>&nbsp;</td><td rowspan="$res" style="$tue">$myrow[show]</td>"; break;
  }
  <tr>
   <td>$val</td>$tds
  </tr>
 $row++;
 }     
</table>
```

Now my code works fine generating the the table with the rowspan, but I know I have to remove the necessary td's in the next rows depending on how many rows my rowspan ($res) contain. This is probably the part I'm falling out of the bus :)
What I'm trying to achieve here is to get the row number and 'day td' to hide in the rows that follow

```
// ARRY FOR ROWS TO SKIP TD
if($res >=2){
$rowCount = $res -1;
$rowSkip = $row;
for($i=1;$i <= $rowCount; $i++){
$rowSkip++;
$skip[$rowSkip] = $myrow[show_day];
}
}
// LOOK IF ROW HAVE VALUE
foreach($skip AS $key2 => $val2){
 if($row == "$key2" && $myrow[show_day]="$val2"){
  $$val2 = "display:none";
 }
}
```

I'm not even sure if I'm approaching the whole concept on the right matter, any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You!!

In the end of the day my table should look like this:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR1A1.jpg)

Comment: Can you please give the data what you have?

Comment: day of the show ($myrow[show_day]) 
Start Time of show (time_start) 
Stop Time of Show (time_stop) 
Show Name ($myrow[show])

Comment: okay i want just array. not an issue i will make it my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fill answer

Well i don't have good time to cake an full array but hopefully it will work for you.

```
<?php
$times = array('00:00','00:30', '01:00', '01:30','02:00','02:30','03:00');
$days = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'); // 0 = Sun ... 6 = Sat


$shows = array();

$shows[] =   array(
    "day"=>0,
    "time_start"=>'00:00',
    "time_end"=>'00:30',
    "name"=>"Show A"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>1,
    "time_start"=>'00:00',
    "time_end"=>'00:30',
    "name"=>"Show B"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>3,
    "time_start"=>'00:00',
    "time_end"=>'00:30',
    "name"=>"Show C"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>4,
    "time_start"=>'00:00',
    "time_end"=>'00:30',
    "name"=>"Show D"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>5,
    "time_start"=>'00:00',
    "time_end"=>'00:30',
    "name"=>"Show E"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>6,
    "time_start"=>'00:00',
    "time_end"=>'00:30',
    "name"=>"Show F"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>1,
    "time_start"=>'00:30',
    "time_end"=>'01:30',
    "name"=>"Show G"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>2,
    "time_start"=>'00:30',
    "time_end"=>'01:00',
    "name"=>"Show H"
    );
$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>3,
    "time_start"=>'00:30',
    "time_end"=>'01:00',
    "name"=>"Show I"
    );
$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>4,
    "time_start"=>'00:30',
    "time_end"=>'01:00',
    "name"=>"Show J"
    );
$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>1,
    "time_start"=>'01:00',
    "time_end"=>'01:30',
    "name"=>"Show K"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>2,
    "time_start"=>'01:00',
    "time_end"=>'02:00',
    "name"=>"Show L"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>1,
    "time_start"=>'01:30',
    "time_end"=>'02:00',
    "name"=>"Show M"
    );

$shows[] = array(
    "day"=>2,
    "time_start"=>'01:30',
    "time_end"=>'02:00',
    "name"=>"Show N"
    );

$parsedShow = array();

foreach ($shows as  $show) {

    $start_index =  array_search($show['time_start'], $times); // $key = 2;
    $end_index =  array_search($show['time_end'], $times); // $key = 1;

    if($end_index - $start_index > 1){
        //NEED SPAN
        $show['span'] = (($end_index - $start_index));
    }else{
        $show['span'] = false;
    }
    $parsedShow[$show['time_start']][] = $show;
}

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($parsedShow);

// die();
?>
<html>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Time
        </td>
        <?php 
        foreach ($days as $day) {
            echo "<td>$day</td>";
        }
        ?>

    </tr>
    <?php 
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <?php 
            if(!isset($parsedShow[$time])){
                continue;
            }
            echo "<td>$time</td>";
            foreach ($parsedShow[$time] as $show) {
                ?>
                <td <?= ($show['span'] !== false ? "rowSpan='".$show['span']."'" : "")?>><?= $show['name'] ?></td>
                <?php }
                ?>
            </tr>
            <?php }

            ?>
        </table>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thank allot, it's much appreciated, will implement it now.